# Where does VISA go on the OSI stack?

Tags: ssh, visa, osi

I am looking at putting together a communications protocol for an embedded application, but I don't know much about high-level communications such as TCP/IP, etc. I'm more used to dealing with bits and bytes on [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) and [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus), etc.

Someone has suggested that I use a [VISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument_Software_Architecture) (virtual instrument software architecture) I/O API with [SCPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments) (standard commands for programmable instruments) command syntax. What layer would these sit at on the OSI model? I'm thinking VISA would be application and SCPI presentation?

Someone else has suggested using SSH, again as I'm not sure what layer VISA/SCPI sits at, I don't know how SSH would affect the design.

Comment: Okay, I'll play necromancer, if you haven't solved this yet: what is the embedded application supposed to do?

Comment: Id kinda givin up worrying about it! But the application sends and receives SCPI data over SSH, potentially by using the VISA API.

Comment: well, this is two applications sending messages to one another over a network?

Comment: and I'm assuming they're passing data back and forth over stdout/stdin?

Comment: yup two applications communicating, SSH client on pc and ssh server on embedded server device (which converts to UART serial and sends out on a serial line to microcontroller)

Comment: Okay, so these are running at layer 7(application) in the OSI model, which I expected the case to be, given that they aren't network but hardware interface protocols. Next question is: do you need the authentication/encryption of ssh, or was it just an expedient solution at the time?

Comment: Not particularly, just had the SSH drivers already on the control system that will be standing in for the PC in the future so the guys on that end said they'd go with that... I dont know enough about networking to argue with their decision and my supe, Ok'd it so..

Comment: For future reference, you'd probably just want to open a tcp connection between the two endpoints, and then dup2() stdin/stdout to the socket; it should be entirely transparent to the application at that point. Note, of course that basic tcp does no validation that the data being fed to it is at all really from the desired source, so caveat emptor on that. If you want, I can throw some wrapper code down, but it's really trivial enough that you should be able to come up with it on your own as a learning tool.

Comment: Thanks @tbert If you want to make your layer 7 comment an answer, Ill select it as one. I'll leave the tcp connection to the guys on the control system. My system can handle whatever's thrown at it already with only a few configuration changes on the server. At this stage I just need to be able to describe it properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're basically just using the network to pass data between a hardware API and an application, you're on layer 7(application) of the OSI stack.